# Expandable list is not displaying

Tags: android

I am creating a expandable list where each list contains set of object (Product). But in get children count I am getting null pointer exception and not displaying the list.

```
private Activity context;
private ArrayList<Product> allBmcList;
Map<ArrayList<Product>, List<String>> bmcCollection;
private List<String> Groups;



public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> groups,
        Map<ArrayList<Product>, List<String>> bmcList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.bmcCollection = bmcList;
    this.Groups = groups;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // Below line I am getting null pointer exception.


    return bmcCollection.get(Groups.get(groupPosition)).size();
}
```

Comment: post Map<ArrayList<Product>, List<String>> bmcList code

Comment: Loading is not a problem I am getting value BMC collection. I think problem is only while get children count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right:

`Groups.get(groupPosition))` returns a string from the List, which is then given as a parameter to `bmcCollection.get(string)`

Now bmcCollection is a [map](/questions/tagged/map), and in the API is strictly said:

Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or **null if this map contains no mapping for the key**.

Therefore it returns null, which triggers the exception after calling size() method.

**EDIT:** considering comments.

I am gonna go ahead and assume that the list `List<String>` in the map is the same is list as `List<String> groups`. Therefore I would use this kind of map:

`Map<String, ArrayList<Product>> bmcCollection;` where String is the name of the group and the list are its children.

**Then following should work:**

```
String group_name = Groups.get(groupPosition);
List<String> children = bmcCollection.get(name);
return children.size()
```

or shorter:

`(bmcCollection.get(Groups.get(groupPosition))).size()`

Comment: Thank you Kuba, but what is the solution here.

Comment: @u_pendra what does the list `List<String>` in the map contain?

Answer (score 2):

try with this:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
 int size = 0;
 if (bmcCollection.get(Groups.get(groupPosition)).size() != null)
 size = bmcCollection.get(Groups.get(groupPosition)).size();
 return size;
}
```

Comment: Piyush, I think you are trying to compare int value with null.

Comment: no....its not i have faced with same problem and after this it was solved.... so i don't think so